# Display some arbitrary HTML or content in a sidebar

Tags: plugin-recommendation, widgets

I need to have a bit of frequently changing content in a sidebar (the time and location of the next meeting of a club).

What I'd really like is a nice widget that displays `the_content()` of a selected page or just has a rich text field and displays what's in that. I figured there would be something like this around, but I can't find it. (Maybe because the search terms are too cloudy and overloaded?)

I wrote a widget that displays `the_content()` of a hardcoded page, but that's not an ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks! It's a mystery I didn't find any of those on my own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [Rich Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rich-widget/)?

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recomend using the [Rich Text Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rich-text-widget/) as it uses the built in TinyMCE editor that comes with WordPress and doesn't add any extra javascript etc

Answer (score 1):

[Spectacu.la Page Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/spectacula-page-widget/)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the [Black Studio TinyMCE Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/) plugin, which adds a WYSIWYG text widget based on the standard TinyMCE WordPress editor.

Comment: Please mention your affiliation. Also copy/pasting identical answers around is poor practice, please try to elaborate how needs of specific questions are addressed in every case.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning I was the author of the plugin. And sorry for the copy/paste too.

Answer (score 0):

try using custom content widget, it adds a "content block" in the dashboard just under the pages, its easy to use http://www.vanderwijk.com/wordpress/wordpress-custom-post-widget/